# Is there any way to find nodes having a property with closest integer values with respect to an argument in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cql

I need to search nodes having property "totalValue", now i need to find 10 nodes having value closest to 100. I need some help to write a query which can return me required results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the *distance*, order by *distance*, limit to 10 ...

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n.totalValue AS value, abs(100 - n.totalValue) AS distance
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: I think that you need to add a "property exists" check: `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE EXISTS(n.totalValue)...`

Comment: You don't always need to check for existence. In this answer, if the node does not have the `totalValue` property, then `distance` will be `NULL`. When you `ORDER BY` a property, `NULL` values will be considered greater than all non-NULL values. Since the query is sorting in ascending order, this would effectively hide the nodes without that property (unless fewer than 10 nodes have that property).